# Pumba installation - Command not found on linux terminal

Tags: linux

I am trying to install pumba from the OS release page. Once it is downloaded, I try running

```
pumba --help
```

It gives a command not found error.

Can anyone suggest what am I missing? The amd_64 file has all read, write and execute permissions.

Comment: What is the name of the amd_64 file?

Comment: I think, that's only an installer.

Comment: pumba_linux_amd64

Comment: What is the output of `file pumba_linux_amd64`?

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the file is `pumba_linux_amd64`, you have to use that. Additionally, since the file is (assuming) not in your `$PATH`, you can't launch it directly.

If your file is in your current directory, run

```
./pumba_linux_amd64
```